# Spliting one row of record into multiple between two date

Tags: sql-server

Can anybody help me out to do this:

My table data is like

```
Datefiled       Field1     Field2    Field2   Field4
01-01-2012     ABC         10        15         17
01-04-2013     PQR          7        80         65
01-05-2014     XYZ         15        25         77
```

The output would look something like this

```
Month/Year       Field1     Field2    Field2   Field4
01/2012            ABC         10        15         17
02/2012            ABC         10        15         17
03/2012            ABC         10        15         17
04/2012            ABC         10        15         17

.....
03/2013           ABC         10         15         17

04/2013           PQR          7          80         65
05/2013           PQR          7          80         65
06/2013           PQR          7          80         65
07/2013           PQR          7          80         65
.......
04/2014           PQR          7          80         65

05/2014           XYZ         15          25         77
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a calendar table, either one row per day or one row per month, and you can use a tally table (=virtual, constructed for example with a CTE) too and do something like this:

```
select
  *
from
  calendar c
  cross apply (
    select top 1 *
    from yourtable y
    where y.Datefiled < c.calendardate
    order by Datefiled desc
  ) y
```

Comment: thanks for reply, can u post the details of calendar tables structure i.e fieldname, value

Comment: @sapabin No, that's for you to do. If you don't know how to do that, google.

Comment: created one table named calendar with field calendardate. inserted all months first date upto some date. Not getting the result month then year wise. I mean 01/2012,02/2012, 03/2012,04/2012 .....so on instead getting 01/2012,01/2013,01/2014,01/2015, 02/2012,02/2013.....so on

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH datat as (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('2012-01-01', 'ABC', 10, 15, 17),('2012-12-12', 'LKJ', 16, 12, 13),
('2013-01-15', 'CVB', 16, 11, 19),('2013-04-01', 'PQR',  7, 80, 65),
('2014-04-24', 'XYZ', 15, 25, 77),('2014-05-17', 'DEF', 12, 40, 50)
) as t(Datefiled, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4)
), cte AS (
SELECT CAST(MIN(Datefiled) AS DATE) as date_,
       CAST(MAX(Datefiled) AS DATE) AS maxd
FROM datat
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(day,1,date_), maxd
FROM cte 
WHERE date_ < maxd
)

SELECT CAST([Month] as nvarchar(2)) + '/' + CAST([Year] as nvarchar(4)) as [Month/Year],
        Field1,
        Field2,
        Field3,
        Field4  
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT  
        MONTH(date_) as [Month],
        YEAR(date_) as [Year],
        Field1,
        Field2,
        Field3,
        Field4
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES  CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, d1.Datefiled ), 0) as date) as [DateStart],
                                    CAST(DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, d2.Datefiled), 0)) as date) as [DateEnd],
                                    d1.Field1,
                                    d1.Field2,
                                    d1.Field3,
                                    d1.Field4
            FROM datat d1
            LEFT JOIN datat d2
                ON d1.Datefiled < d2.Datefiled
            ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d1.Datefiled ORDER BY d2.Datefiled)
                ) as d
        ON c.date_ between d.[DateStart] and ISNULL(d.[DateEnd],c.date_)
        WHERE Field1 IS NOT NULL
        ) as t 
    ORDER BY [Year], [Month]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Output:

```
Month/Year Field1 Field2      Field3      Field4
---------- ------ ----------- ----------- -----------
1/2012     ABC    10          15          17
2/2012     ABC    10          15          17
3/2012     ABC    10          15          17
4/2012     ABC    10          15          17
5/2012     ABC    10          15          17
6/2012     ABC    10          15          17
7/2012     ABC    10          15          17
8/2012     ABC    10          15          17
9/2012     ABC    10          15          17
10/2012    ABC    10          15          17
11/2012    ABC    10          15          17
12/2012    LKJ    16          12          13
1/2013     CVB    16          11          19
2/2013     CVB    16          11          19
3/2013     CVB    16          11          19
4/2013     PQR    7           80          65
5/2013     PQR    7           80          65
6/2013     PQR    7           80          65
7/2013     PQR    7           80          65
8/2013     PQR    7           80          65
9/2013     PQR    7           80          65
10/2013    PQR    7           80          65
11/2013    PQR    7           80          65
12/2013    PQR    7           80          65
1/2014     PQR    7           80          65
2/2014     PQR    7           80          65
3/2014     PQR    7           80          65
4/2014     XYZ    15          25          77
5/2014     DEF    12          40          50

(29 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: everything works fine with this new code except for this portion    SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('2012-01-01', 'ABC', 10, 15, 17),
('2013-04-01', 'PQR',  7, 80, 65),
('2014-05-01', 'XYZ', 15, 25, 77)
) as t(Datefiled, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4)
)              ----- what I want is instead of fixed value I will select  Datefiled, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 from a table using where clause.

Comment: That is an emulation of yourtable, you must remove this part and put there your table name.

Comment: everything works fine with this new code except for this portion    SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('2012-01-01', 'ABC', 10, 15, 17),
('2013-04-01', 'PQR',  7, 80, 65),
('2014-05-01', 'XYZ', 15, 25, 77)
) as t(Datefiled, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4)
)              ----- what I want is instead of fixed value I will select  Datefiled, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 from a table using where clause.   So data for the first date's mm/yyyy is showing null i.e if datefiled's first date is 24-12-2012 then for 12/2012 filed1 ....filed4 showing null. From 01/2013 onwards all the correct data is showing

Comment: Well, in cte part you must put dates of start (first select) and finish(where part) that you need

Comment: Tried quote datat as (select * from tablename where .....) as t  getting error incorrect syntax near as

Comment: Select * problem has been solved but data for the month of first datefiled value i.e 24-12-2012 which should be 12/2012 is not coming. Result is like that    Month/Year        filed1 filed2  filed3 filed4                                           12/2012  Null Null Null Null                  01/2013 ABC  10 15 17

Comment: Now I find that as the data is showing from next month of first datevalue of  datefiled's and it is exeeding to the next month of the last datevalue of datefiled i.e if last date is 31/01/2016 data is showing upto 02/2016

Comment: That is the problem, what if you have `2016-01-01, ABC` and then `2016-02-28 DEF` what should be near `02/2016`? `ABC` or `DEF`? In your sample of data I see only first day of month and no word about that there could be other values like `2012-12-24`.

Comment: on 02/2016 it should be DEF. It would be better if the Starting date will be dynamic means first date value of the Datefiled instead of fixed one i.e '2012-01-01'   and the rows filed1, filed2, filed3, filed4 value will change based on the month/year value of the date of the Datefiled.means when Datefiled value will 28-02-2016 that corresponding filed1 to filed4 value ( DEF....) should appear in 02/2016.

Comment: Consider this                   Datefiled       Field1     Field2    Field2   Field4
01-01-2012     ABC         10        15         17
22-04-2013     PQR          7        80         65
15-05-2014     XYZ         15        25         77                                             and output like  03/2013           ABC         10         15         17
04/2013           PQR          7          80         65
.......
04/2014           PQR          7          80         65                     05/2014           XYZ         15          25         77                 Also firstdate may vary

Comment: can u post the code where instead of fixed value of date_   column   I want to use starting date value of the Datefiled i.e in place of '2012-01-01' it should be First(Datefiled) or Min(Datefiled)

Comment: I add your request to the query.

Comment: In place of this SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('2012-01-01', 'ABC', 10, 15, 17),('2012-12-12', 'LKJ', 16, 12, 13),
.....) as t(Datefiled, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4)
), cte AS (     I have written Select * from tablename where .... ), cte AS then all months data showing correctly except where the consecutive two months data is there previous one is not showing means 24/04/2014  abc ... and then 17/05/2014 xyz .... 24/04/2014 not coming (04/14 is not appearing)

Comment: Try it one more time :) I have made some changes to query. Hope it will work fine for you :)

Comment: So, did you check it?